# Cannot GET /app/index.html

Tags: node.js, express

project directory structure is

```
school-data
 |  
 +-- app
 |  |  
 |  +-- app.js
 |  |
 |  +-- app.css
 |  |
 |  +-- server.js
 |  |
 |  +-- mini.js
 |  |
 |  +-- index.html
 |    
 +-- home
 |      
 +-- node_modules
 |  |  
 |  |-- modules (like express)
```

and file `server.js` code is

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../public"));

app.get("/", function (req,res) {
    res.send("server : i am working")
});

var server = app.listen(8081, function() {
    console.log(new Date().toISOString() + ": server started on port 8081"); 
});
```

I am trying to access http://localhost:8081/app/index.html from browser and getting 404 error while http://localhost:8081 working fine for me

Comment: You did not specify correct directory & file structure as well please post formatted code. Probably you are doing something wrong in path in `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../public"));`. In you folder structure, where is public folder and which file code you have posted?

Comment: Arif khan plz help me what can i do?how to make i directory & file structure. how to post  formatted code.i am first time post on this site. thanks for reply

Comment: Can you confirm updated question or update directory structure and question as per your need? So that we can reply your on your question

Comment: you should play with https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator to start with expressjs

Answer (score 1):

Even you directory structure is not good but here is code that may help you.

You should update your `server.js` file as following

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");

var app = express();

//all routes start with /app will be redirected to app folder as public
app.use("/app", express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../app')));

app.get("/", function (req,res) {
    res.send("server : i am working")
});

var server = app.listen(8081, function() {
    console.log(new Date().toISOString() + ": server started on port 8081"); 
});
```